# How to fetch table records according to array of ids?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I am doing project in laravel. I want to display all records according to the array containing ids of column.

I have array as,

```
$prov_Data  =  ["11","15","3","7","8","2","4"];
```

and I want to fetch all records from provider table whose ids are 11,15,3,7,... serially.

For that when I did as,

```
$providerData = Provider::whereIn('id',$prov_Data)->get();
```

then returned data is as 2,3,4,... i.e. in asc order. I want data in 11,15,3,... order only.

Comment: can't you just use an "orderBy('id')" or something like that ?
like the docs say :

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderBy

Comment: no its not working. I don't want data in asc or desc order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `order by field` feature :

```
$prov_Data  =  ["11","15","3","7","8","2","4"];
$ids = implode(',', $prov_Data);
$providers = Provider::whereIn('id', $prov_Data)->orderByRaw("FIELD (id, $ids) ASC")->get();
```

> Tested only on mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = ["11","15","3","8","2","4","7"];
$list = implode(',', $array);
$data = Provider::whereIn('id', $array)->orderByRaw("FIELD (id, $list) ASC")->get();
return $data;
```